# Why does the FIX names change frequently for the approach courses for a given airport?

Tags: airspace, approach, instrument-procedures, precision-approach, procedure-design

I have seen the name of fixes change as published in the approach plate for airports like DFW, ORD. The approach path seems to be the same. For example, sometime over the last year the FAF for 18L at DFW changed from HASTY to JAYCI.

Any reason for this frequent change? As an additional question, do the minimum altitudes published for an approach path change often?